# Cannot resolve symbol NameValuePair

Tags: java, android, sdk

In my project I got an error:

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Then I tried to fix it use this:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

But then I got error:

> cannot resolve symbol NameValuePair android

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`NameValuePair` is part the package `org.apache` which was deprecated with `Android 22` and removed with `Android M`, which is the version against you are compiling. What is interesting is that neither the documentation of [NameValuePair](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/NameValuePair.html) is reachable

Comment: look for a replacement ? What are you using it for ?

Comment: my all project use `org.apache.http` this `NameValuePair`, `BasicNameValuePair`

Comment: than you have to migrate it to URLConnection or some other http client

Comment: Then how to make android all version compatible class,(android 2.3 to N) ?

Comment: Use HttpUrlConnection @devopsEMK

Answer (score 40):

If you want to use **NameValuePair** or **BasicNameValuePair** in android studio with latest API Levels. Then follow steps below:

- Open build.gradle(Module) file and copy these dependencies:

  ```
  implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'

  implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'

  implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+'
  ```
- Copy `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` below `buildToolsVersion` like:

  ```
  android {
  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'}
  ```

Thats all. Now just sync gradle file.

**Note:** In dependencies i recommend to use latest version of libraries instead of + symbol.

Comment: Why would Gson be needed ?

Comment: Worked for me by only adding 'useLibrary' line. thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Today i also had same problem. I solved with two changes in my build.gradle

```
 1)   android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
              }

2)  compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

My final build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.corouter"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
dependencies
        {
            compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
            compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
            compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'

        }
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot..Your solution Worked!!

Comment: your welcome but i'll suggest you to move with volley library because these are deprecated...

Comment: Yaa..i will definitely look into it

Comment: thats great. if you need any help...feel free to ask

Answer (score 5):

add this:

```
compile'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

in app based build.gradle it will pick it up

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks! Simple one line solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

Nested class would work:

```
private class NameValuePair {
        private String mName;
        private String mValue;

        public NameValuePair(String name, String value) {
            mName = name;
            mValue = value;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return mName;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return mValue;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. To resolve it, I used:

```
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.message.BasicNameValuePair;
```

and also added

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1"
compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
```

to the app/gradle dependencies. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

**Had the same problem**

Solved it as follows:

1. Add this in dependencies:

**compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'**

2. Add this below targetSdkVersion in defaultConfig

**useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'**