# NameValuePair Error "NameValuePair cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: php, android, mysql

I m new in android and i m creating a project like [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) and its showing the error like the following photo.Please help me out of this.[image]

Comment: Do you have `org.apache.http.NameValuePair` as an import?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke  sir, yes i already import ,its solved now when i change my version sdk to 21,but still error like this http://postimg.org/image/ykjyfg7hj/

Comment: @Boss   ,its solved now when i change my version sdk to 21,but still error like this postimg.org/image/ykjyfg7hj

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your project's `compileSdkVersion` is set to 23. [Apache's HttpClient library was removed from the Android SDK in API Level 23](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).

If you change your `compileSdkVersion` to 21, your app will compile cleanly. Or, there is [a workaround to continue using HttpClient in Android 6.0 with Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client). However, for long-term development, you really need to move to something else for an HTTP API. That "something else" could be:

- the built-in classic Java `HttpUrlConnection`
- Apache's independent packaging of [HttpClient for Android](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)
- [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) (my recommendation)
- [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)

Or, depending upon the nature of your HTTP work, you might choose a library that supports higher-order operations (e.g., Retrofit for Web service APIs).

Comment: I have used Volley for about a month, Retrofit for just a simple project. I have read many topics saying that Retrofit is better than Volley. Today I have just read [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-volley-vs-retrofit-better-approach/) and I find that I prefer Volley like that author :-). However, when have more time, I will learn more about Retrofit

Comment: @BNK: Retrofit and Volley (and Ion and countless others) are not "raw" HTTP clients, but rather are designed for particular sorts of operations (e.g., Retrofit designed for talking to Web services). My bulleted list is a roster of general-purpose HTTP clients, that can perform just about any HTTP action, albeit with more code.

Comment: yes, I see. Relating to raw HTTP clients, I have not searched much about OkHttp. Could you tell me if it supports multipart as Apache's libraries does? I mean MultipartEntityBuilder of Apache HttpMime

Comment: Ah, I find OkHttp well supports multipart :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare wow u r so smart... i just change sdkversion to 21 its wworks now.its really quite smart! Thanks dude

Comment: @CommonsWare  http://postimg.org/image/ykjyfg7hj/    but it still show like that ,if u can help me again ^__^

Comment: @ThanHtut: That is an unrelated problem. I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question related to it, or search for that error message on your favorite search engine.

Comment: @CommonsWare side question using okhttp doesnt need asynctask right ? and AndroidAsync is different then asynctask .. correct?

Comment: @Moudiz: "using okhttp doesnt need asynctask right ?" -- OkHttp has its own asynchronous methods, which you can safely call from the main application thread. "and AndroidAsync is different then asynctask" -- yes.

Comment: If anyone want to use NameValuePair in latest API levels, can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35766284/4531507