# How to get data from JSON - HttpClient deprecated

Tags: android, json, httpclient

I used to get `JSON` data from the code below but now with `HttpClient` deprecated I cannot anymore. Could you help me please?

```
String responseString = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI apiCall = new URI("...");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(apiCall);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "some sort of problem encountered", e);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380439/namevaluepair-error-namevaluepair-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type

Comment: Thanks for the comment @CommonsWare , if you write an answer I'll accept it as correct.
But why if I compile my gradle with https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html or http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client my code is not correct?

Comment: @CommonsWare: looks like that you mark duplicate of another duplicated question :-)

Comment: @BNK: Oops! Too late now...

Answer (score 0):

Use another class like

```
   URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
 }
```

Comment: How can I adapt it to an AsyncTask?