# okhttp not displaying message in logcat

Tags: android, okhttp

I am trying `OkHttp` examples in this below code I was expecting some printing message, however I am not recieving anything , can you tell me why?

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public void run() throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
    for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
    }

    System.out.println(response.body().string());
}
```

this is the logcat

```
Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-N900_4.4.2_0040
09-25 11:19:24.695  28481-28481/? I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
09-25 11:19:24.695  28481-28481/? E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
09-25 11:19:24.695  28481-28481/? E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.justapps.ak [ userId:0 | appId:10203 ]
09-25 11:19:24.700  28481-28481/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
PLATFORM VERSION : JB-MR-2
D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000
D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: Have you put it inside `doInBackground` of asynctask yet?

Comment: I am using `okhttp` .. does that include to add `doinbackground`?Do we use doinbackground in asynchtask ? in the examples they didnt mention that @BNK

Comment: You have to do so :), I check your code, it works in the asynctask

Comment: @BNK I am learning OkHttp because in the latest SDK I cant work with asynctask.. check please the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380439/namevaluepair-error-namevaluepair-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type/32380569?noredirect=1#comment53247496_32380569

Comment: How does your project use okhttp, my project includes `okhttp-2.5.0.jar` and `okio-1.6.0.jar` in `libs` folder

Comment: @BNK sorry I didnt understand your question

Comment: I mean  that how does your project include Okhttp library. Have you downloaded the jar file from http://square.github.io/okhttp/?

Comment: its in my Gradle file , 
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}

Comment: I try `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'` instead of Jar files, must have asynctask also

Comment: Ah, you can read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135338/okhttp-library-networkonmainthreadexception-on-simple-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, please try the following code:

```
    private class VoidRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            MyOkHttpRequest request = new MyOkHttpRequest();
            try {
                request.run();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class MyOkHttpRequest {
        private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        public void run() throws IOException {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
            for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
            }
            System.out.println(response.body().string());
        }
    }
```

Then in `onCreate()`, call `new VoidRequest().execute();`

Comment: I had to create 2 activities for that ,can I have them in one activity ?

Comment: Why 2 activities? My sample project has only one MainActivity :)

Comment: ok thank it worked . but there is something I didnt get it , if you can help me please .. I am using Okhttp to avoid using asynctask,(as I explained in the link) why then in above example we used asynctask ?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135338/okhttp-library-networkonmainthreadexception-on-simple-post for OkHttp's async method :)

Comment: Yes I am reading , the piece of code where should be added ? call post string(url ... ?

Comment: Tomorrow I will try OkHttp async more. Actually, I start learning OkHttp like you :-)

Comment: oh thats good , can you please when you learn it show me your way how to upload an image and receive it from server ? because I am learning to do that , and I want to compare your way with my way. if you will do that tell me

Comment: Yes, I see, however, why don't you try Retrofit or Volley for that? :)

Comment: I am using picasso , with that I need something like OkHttp right?

Comment: I haven't used Piccaso, however I see many people recommend it :-)

Comment: ah yes its better than volley, I started with volley but it caused me headech so I started with picasso . its simple.