# Android Studio error with NameValuePair

Tags: java, android

Here's the bit of relevant code:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age + ""));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

        return null;
    }
```

It's telling me "Cannot resolve symbol NameValuePair" and the same thing for "BasicNameValuePair."

Is that syntax incorrect? Because I am pretty sure that both of those exist in Java.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If anyone want to use NameValuePair in latest API levels, can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35766284/4531507

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair` and `org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair` and add 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1' to your gradle dependencies.