# How to fix cannot resolve "NameValuePair"

Tags: android

```
   protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){
   ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend=new ArrayList<>();
   dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",user.name));
   dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age",user.age));
   dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",user.username));
   dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",user.password));
```

Cannot resolve symbol `NameValuePair`.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve symbol NameValuePair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121031/cannot-resolve-symbol-namevaluepair)

Answer (score 0):

add this in your **build.gradle** for further [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121031/cannot-resolve-symbol-namevaluepair)

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using target sdk 23...its deprecated in sdk 22 so you could not use it in sdk 23.

the way to use NameValuePair in sdk23 use library 
**useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'**

in you **build.gradle**

like

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
```

Comment: 'android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}'

Comment: 'code'android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}'code'

Comment: but my compilesdkversion is 24, still cannot fix ,T.T

Answer (score 0):

`NameValuePair` is deprecated and you can use Maps instead of it . also you can use `Uri` class to build urls and append to url parameters you want . another good way to send request and get info from net is using libraries such as Retrofit or volley than they have very good performance